# Can't find referenced class kotlin.internal.annotations.AvoidUninitializedObjectCopyingCheck

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-experimental

When ProGuard is enabled for an Android project with Kotlin, the Gradle build fails with the following error:

> Warning: HomeChargerLocation: can't find
> referenced class
> kotlin.internal.annotations.AvoidUninitializedObjectCopyingCheck
>
> Warning: HomeChargerLocation$Address:
> can't find referenced class
> kotlin.internal.annotations.AvoidUninitializedObjectCopyingCheck
>
> Warning: HomeChargerLocation$Address$Creator:
> can't find referenced class
> kotlin.internal.annotations.AvoidUninitializedObjectCopyingCheck
>
> Warning: HomeChargerLocation$Car: can't
> find referenced class
> kotlin.internal.annotations.AvoidUninitializedObjectCopyingCheck
>
> Warning:
> HomeChargerLocation$Car$Creator: can't
> find referenced class
> kotlin.internal.annotations.AvoidUninitializedObjectCopyingCheck
>
> Warning: HomeChargerLocation$Creator:
> can't find referenced class
> kotlin.internal.annotations.AvoidUninitializedObjectCopyingCheck
>
> Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please
> correct the above warnings first.

The corresponding classes: https://gist.github.com/makovkastar/cfa4bf1bea38556279f20eef46001cf8

I assume it has something to do with the `@Parcelize` annotation from the Kotlin experimental package, because the problem appeared when we started using it.

**UPDATE**: I have created an issue in the Kotlin bug tracker -
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21628

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue has been [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21628) in Kotlin 1.2.20.